# Flask Pymongo Objectid link not working

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I am tring to access a new document from a mongo database collection named `games` by the `_id`. But for example if I access `localhost:5000/solutie/5ae71f3e8e442b090e4c313b`it is giving me the error: `ValueError: View function did not return a response` so it doesn't go through the `if` and I think I should convert the value of the `_id` to another type but I don't know how.

This is my flask code:

```
@app.route('/solutie/<id>')
def solu(id):
    games = mongo.db.games
    game_user = games.find_one({'_id' : id})
    if game_user:
        return id
```

This is my mongo database collection named `games`:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ae71f3e8e442b090e4c313b"
    },
    "sursa1": "nothingfornow",
    "sursa2": "nothing4now",
    "corectat": 0,
    "player2": "test",
    "player1": "test2",
    "trimis1": 1,
    "trimis2": 1
}
```

Comment: You'll need to make an `ObjectId` from the string id before you query the collection... `games.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(id)})`

Answer (score 0):

There's an object type converter you can use for URL routing:

```
@app.route('/solutie/<ObjectID:game_id>')
def solu(game_id):
    games = mongo.db.games
    game_user = games.find_one_or_404({'_id' : game_id})
    return game_user
```

See:
https://flask-pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_pymongo.BSONObjectIdConverter

Also, don't override `id()` because this is an in-built Python function.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of the find() method is an object describing which fields to include in the result.
This parameter is optional and if omitted, all fields are included in the result.

```
# @app.route('/solutie/<int:id>') # or
@app.route('/solutie/<string:id>')
def solu(id):
   myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
   mydb = myclient["mydatabase"]
   games = mydb["games"]

   game_user = games.find({},{ "_id": id})
   if game_user is not None:
       return id
   else:
     return render_template("index.html")
```

Also you should use "else" condition.